# Prove by Structural induction, circular permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, permutations

> Prove by Structural Induction:
>   For a circular permutation of $n$ elements, the number of permutations is $(n-1)!$

How is this done?

Comment: By induction, as the task says. Please show your own efforts. Maybe write down the definition for "structural induction" at least and tell us where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seat one person at a (circular) table:  $P(1) = 1 (=0!)$.

Seat the second person at the table.  There's only one place for them to go, so $P(2) = 1(=1!)$.

Seat the third person at the table.  That person can be seated with Person 1 on his left, or Person 2 on his left.  So $P(3) = 2 \cdot P(2) = 2(=2!).$

Seat the fourth person.  That person can be seated with any of the three people at the table on his left.  So $P(4) = 3 \cdot P(2) = 3 \cdot 2 = 6 = 3!.$

Seat the $n$th person.  That person can be seated with any of the already-seated $n-1$ people on his left.  So $P(n) = (n-1) \cdot  P(n-1) = (n-1)(n-2)\cdots(2)(1) = (n-1)!.$